# jqgrid spacing around each cell when increasing font size

Tags: jqgrid

I have increased the font size on my grid cells with the following css:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Now the spacing around the text in each individual cell is small.  How do I increase that space so the bigger text will display correctly in each cell?

Thanks Before Hand

**Update # 1**

I have added the following css according to Oleg's suggestion:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    padding:  5px 1em 5px 1em;
}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgfirstrow > td {
    padding:  5px 1em 5px 1em;
}
```

But I am getting a bold line on the top of the first record as seen here:

[image: bold_line]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the following CSS rules

```js
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    padding: 0 .5em 0 .5em;
}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgfirstrow > td {
    padding: 0 .5em 0 .5em;
}
```

You can replace `.5` (`0.5`) to any other value to have the pagging which you need.

Comment: Oleg, thanks that worked but can you see update #1 above.  I am getting a thick line on the first record.  Thank you.

Comment: @RobertSmith: You are welcome! You set `padding-top` and `padding-botom` too. You can do this on all rows with exception `tr.jqgfirstrow`. You should fix your settings and to use for example `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgfirstrow > td { padding:  0 1em 0 1em; }` holding `padding:  5px 1em 5px 1em;` on all other rows.