# How do you have jqGrid re-calculated the column width?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to add a function to programmatically increase/decrease the font size. I intend to use jquery.css() to change the font size, e.g. $(‘#gbox_jqGrid’).css(‘font-size’, ‘8px’)

but how can I have the jqGrid change the column width depending on the font size?

The grid is supposed to have a horizontal scroll bar, therefore the jqGrid option is set as

```
{autowidth: true,
shrinkToFit: false,
forceFit: false}
```

I googled and tried the below code, but it does not work.

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setColProp','CategoryName',{width:500});
var gw = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','width');
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridWidth',gw);
```

http://jsbin.com/vilahedeya/2/edit?html

output:
http://output.jsbin.com/vilahedeya/2

//***************************************************************

Update:
Thank you, Oleg.
I update my demo code to use Guriddo jqGrid v5.2 (paid version). I appreciate the free jqGrid, but it's a company standard that I have to use this paid version.

http://output.jsbin.com/netadu

I want to change font-size dynamically. I am using bootstrap style. All columns' width are specified. If there is not enough space, a horizontal scroll bar will appear.

In my demo code, I can change font size, e.g.

```
$('.demo-jqgrid-container').css('font-size', '6px')
```

http://output.jsbin.com/netadu

Original

[image: original]

Smaller font size

[image]

If the font size is decreased, I need a way to reduce the column size also.
Some function like

for each column:

```
var originalWidth = $('.demo-jqgrid-container').jqgrid('getColumnWidth', 'CategoryName');

var newWidth = originalWidth * 0.8;    

$('.demo-jqgrid-container').jqgrid('setColumnWidth', newwidth);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change *dynamically* `font-size` or you can just use some other font on your page by including CSS like `.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view { font-size: 14px; }`? Do you want use Bootstrap or jQuery UI style or both? Do you want to specify the width of the column explicitly or to allow jqGrid to calculate the optimal width automatically based on the content in the column?

Comment: You use old jqGrid version 4.6 in your demo. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop starting with the end of 2014, contains many features like methods `setColWidth`, `getAutoResizableWidth`, `autoResizeColumn` and `autoResizeAllColumns`. It supports auto-adjustment of the width of column including `autoresizeOnLoad: true` (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column)).

Comment: Moreover the `ui.jqgrid.css` is changed to support Bootsrtap (see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap)). One can additionally easy change the `font-size` of the grid body using `.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view { font-size: 14px; }` or `.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap > .ui-jqgrid-view { font-size: 14px; }` and increase the padding like it's described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38490424/315935).

Comment: Please see my updates. Thanks.